# Laravel query builder - bulk insert - Ignore columns not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel query builder where I am bulk inserting hundreds of rows. I want to insert the column found and ignore the columns not found in table

Here is my code:

```
$proposalOpsEvents = DB::table('table1')->where('proposal_id', $proposal->id)->get();

$proposalOpsEvents = $proposalOpsEvents->toArray();

DB::connection('mysql_archive')->table('archive_table1')->insert($proposalOpsEvents);
```

I get error "Unknown column".

In table 1 new columns are getting added dynamically. I want to ignore the newly added columns when inserting in archive_table1.

For example,

```
DB::table('archive_table1')->insert([
    'email' => 'abc@example.com', //email column found - insert
    'phone' => 0, // phone column found - insert
    'address' => 'A'// address column (newly added) not found - ignore
]);
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: did you used php artisan migrate command from cli

Comment: i dont want to migrate, i want to ignore any newly added columns

Comment: you should create the field , because the reason of doesn't exist field

Comment: Are you sure you wrote " field" instead of "field", there are no spaces in between, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `insertOrIgnore` method?

```php
DB::table('archive_table1')->insertOrIgnore([
    'email' => 'abc@example.com', //email column found - insert
    'phone' => 0, // phone column found - insert
    'address' => 'A'// address column (newly added) not found - ignore
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DB::squemaBuilder

```
$columns=DB::connection('your_connection')->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table_name');
```

This will return an array with all columns names of the table and with array manipulation you can intersect your columns to insert with columns in table.

```
$newData=[
    'email' => 'abc@example.com', //email column found - insert
    'phone' => 0, // phone column found - insert
    'address' => 'A'// address column (newly added) not found - ignore
]; 

$newDataClean=array_intersect_key($newData, array_flip($columns));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to his problem `i want to ignore any newly added columns`.

Comment: I am proposing the solution for: Ignore columns not found in table for prevent the error "Unknown column".